Cannot get django_sendfile2 to work with gunicorn, nginx, docker
Iam writing a webapp to help user create invoices. I manage to create and save the pdfs but I cannot get django_sendfile2 to save them.
This is my django model with the upload_to function:
def claim_path(instance, filename):
    return "archive/{0}_{1}/{2}_{3}/{4}".format(
        instance.guardian.last_name,
        instance.guardian.first_name,
        instance.patient.last_name,
        instance.patient.first_name,
        filename,
    )


class Claim(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey("Patient", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    guardian = models.ForeignKey("Guardian", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField("Start Date")
    end_date = models.DateField("End Date")
    creation_date = models.DateField("Creation Date", default=datetime.now)
    sum = models.IntegerField("Claim Sum")
    pdf = models.FileField("Claim File", upload_to=claim_path)

These are the important sections of settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django_sendfile",
    ...
]

# media
MEDIA_URL = "/protected/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/protected/"

# for django_sendfile2
SENDFILE_BACKEND = "django_sendfile.backends.nginx"
SENDFILE_ROOT = "/protected/"
SENDFILE_URL = "/protected/"

this is the view that should serve the pdf (don't mind the name, later on I want to embed this on the website as a preview):
def show_pdf_preview(request, claim_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        claim = Claim.objects.get(id=claim_id)
        if claim.guardian == request.user.guardian:
            logging.info(f"trying to show pdf preview using filename '{claim.pdf.path}'")
            return sendfile(request, claim.pdf.path)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden

Here is my nginx default.conf:
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /protected/ {
        internal;
        root /protected/;
    }
}

And finally, this is the error message I get on the docker stdout:
nginx            | 2024/06/06 13:08:16 [error] 29#29: *1 open() "/protected/protected/archive/Admin_Admin/Test_Test/2024-06-06_142405.862381.pdf" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /show_pdf_preview/65/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.3:8000/show_pdf_preview/65/", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/show_claims/"
nginx            | 172.18.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2024:13:08:16 +0000] "GET /show_pdf_preview/65/ HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost:8080/show_claims/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" "-"

And yes, the file IS there. I checked it. Several times. I also already checked the file permissions and set them to rwxrwxrwx for testing. I have also been trying around with the backslashes because the django_sendfile2 documentation mentioned faulty paths. All with no success. Can anybody point my to my mistake?
Greetings
André

OK... How stupid can someone be? After trying around the whole day yesterday I realized that the file was indeed there... It was also mounted inside the django container... But not in the nginx container. I have an icebag on my forehead now where my head hit the table.
